# Why won't the legend in my highchart show values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to show the values of my series data in the highchart legend using [this](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/10/Value-In-Legend) and I've tried pretty much all the examples I can find online, specifically adding:

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 35,
    labelFormat: '<span style="color:{color}">{name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f} USD</b> ({point.change:.2f}%)<br/>',
    borderWidth: 0
},
```

But nothing is working in order to show the values of the data in my highchart and to display the highchart vertically to the right. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

http://jsfiddle.net/tobitobetoby/6druu3a2/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legend options do not apply because you placed them in `series` object. I corrected the demo and add couple of additional options, like `layout`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.layout

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1fqvzpdn/